# How do I use python to put the "data" component of this json response into a Data Frame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

How do I use python to put the "data" componenet of this json response into a pandas dataframe?

```
{"data":[{"name":"samplea","val1":null,"val2":"0591","date":"2017-04-11"},{"name":"sampleb","val1":null,"val2":"1111","date":"2017-04-11"}],"result_count":2,"page_size":250,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"credits":1}
```

update:
using json_normalize results in the below error,

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
d = {"data":[{"name":"samplea","val1":None,"val2":"0591","date":"2017-04-11"},{"name":"sampleb","val1":None,"val2":"1111","date":"2017-04-11"}],"result_count":2,"page_size":250,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"credits":1}
```

---

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(d, 'data')
print (df)
         date     name  val1  val2
0  2017-04-11  samplea  None  0591
1  2017-04-11  sampleb  None  1111
```

Comment: That generates an error, TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str. I used your example too and the same error.
 jsonData = '{"data":[{"name":"samplea","val1":null,"val2":"0591","date":"2017-04-11"},{"name":"sampleb","val1":null,"val2":"1111","date":"2017-04-11"}],"result_count":2,"page_size":250,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1,"credits":1}'
    df = json_normalize(jsonData, 'data')